# emacs gives warning when trying to save files over sshfs

Tags: emacs, fuse, sshfs

I mount an sshfs file system with

```
% sshfs remote.host.org:/home/jrm /home/mnt/remote.host
```

then edit a file under this file system with

```
% emacsclient -n /home/mnt/remote.host/some_file.c.
```

When I save the file I get the warning

```
some_file.c has changed since visited or saved.  Save anyway? (yes or no)
```

Other editors don't have this problem.  What is causing this?  How can I prevent it?  Both hosts are running ntp and the times are the same.

TIA.

P.S. I'm aware that I can open the files directly with tramp, but I prefer sshfs assuming I can get rid of this warning every time I try to save a file.

Comment: Is the modification time of the local file updated after you make a change, save the file, and answer 'yes' to the prompt?

Comment: Hey @LukeGirvin; No, strangely it's not.

Comment: Oh, no wait it is updated.  There just seems to be a lag.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `auto-save-visited-file-name`?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I have '(auto-save-file-name-transforms (quote ((".*/\\([^/]*\\)" "~/.emacs.d/.emacs_auto_saves/\\1" t)))) in the custom set variables section of ~/.emacs so that auto-saved files are all put under ~/.emacs.d/emacs_auto_saves/

Comment: Don't think this would be relevant, but try running Emacs with the -q flag just in case and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and one solution is to just ignore the warnings that the file has changed if you're sure you won't be writing over something important.

I wrote a small minor mode to ignore all file change warnings called modtime-skip-mode

you can find the repo here:
https://github.com/jordonbiondo/modtime-skip-mode

this package is also on Marmalade so if you have that setup you can just

`M-x: package-install <enter> modtime-skip-mode <enter>`